# Convert a nested json (mixpanel api raw data export) into CSV? (Ideally in Python)

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, mixpanel

I have received raw data from the Mixpanel API.  I am hoping to convert it to a CSV file so I can manipulate the data in Excel. I have tried this online tool (http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/), but it does not appear to deal with the nested json results.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is example output:

```
{"event":"Event.Name","properties":{"time":1376784014,"distinct_id":"distinctID","$app_version":"1.XX","$city":"cityName","$ios_ifa":"iosIfa","$lib_version":"X.Y.Z","$manufacturer":"Apple","$model":"model","$os":"iPhone OS","$os_version":"X.Y.Z","$region":"Region","$screen_height":999,"$screen_width":999,"$wifi":true,"App Version":"1.XX","BattleDuration":"99","BattleNum":"2","Episode Num":"2","PlayerVictory":"1","mp_country_code":"CODE","mp_device_model":"Model","mp_lib":"iphone"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is just one of many records you might be dealing with. Basically, you need to convert your JSON object to a flatter object without nesting while not losing the keys and their relationships.

This...

```
{
    "event":"Event.Name",
    "properties":{
        "time":1376784014,
        "distinct_id":"distinctID",
    ....
    ....
}
```

could be converted to... (You can replace _ with any other separator)

```
{
    "mixpanel_event":"Event.Name",
    "mixpanel_properties_time":"1376784014",
    "mixpanel_properties_distinct_id":"distinctID",
    ....
    ....
}
```

Then, you could use the csv.DictWriter to write this structure to a csv file.

You can use a recursive function like this...

```
def reduce_item(key, value):
    global reduced_item

    #Reduction Condition 1
    if type(value) is list:
        i=0
        for sub_item in value:
            reduce_item(key+'_'+str(i), sub_item)
            i=i+1

    #Reduction Condition 2
    elif type(value) is dict:
        sub_keys = value.keys()
        for sub_key in sub_keys:
            reduce_item(key+'_'+str(sub_key), value[sub_key])

    #Base Condition
    else:
        reduced_item[str(key)] = str(value)
```

Then you could call this function like...

```
raw_data = json.loads("your_json_string")
reduced_item = {}
reduce_item("mixpanel", raw_data)
```

I've written a script to do this. You can look at the complete code on [Github](https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv). A detailed explanation can be found [here](http://askvinay.com/index.php?id=13&title=Converting-Nested-JSON-to-CSV).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the sample code give below. You can use recursive functions to get keys and values (you have to somehow ensure that the order is maintained)

```
import sys
import json

def getKeys(newDict):
    retv = []
    for key in newDict.keys():
        try:
            keyForEmbeddedDict = newDict[key].keys()
            retv.extend(getKeys(newDict[key]))
        except AttributeError:
            retv.append(key)      
    return retv

def getValues(newDict):
    retv = []
    for key in newDict.keys():
        try:
            keyForEmbeddedDict = newDict[key].keys()
            retv.extend(getValues(newDict[key]))
        except AttributeError:
            retv.append(newDict[key])      
    return retv

def main():
    t = {}
    filename = '' # Add your filename
    with open(filename) as f:
        t = json.load(f)
    keys = getKeys(t)
    result = getValues(t)

    print keys
    print result
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```